# How do I put in cache a third party image

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm running a website and I'm trying to get the best score in Performance using LightHouse

I did put in cache all the png/svg/... that I had created (Cache-Control : public, max-age=31536000)

But all Image comming from a third party website do not have any of that

Here is my question :
**How can I put these Image in cache ?**

here is how I call them (nothing particuliar):

```html
<img
    class="myclass"
    src="https://............."
    alt="my image"
    loading="lazy"
/>
```

I'm using vuejs so it is in a component

I'm using nuxt and gcloud

Do tell if you need more information.

Comment: If you (soft) reload the page, is the call to your image done another time (check your browser devtools, network tab)?

Comment: yes a soft reload  do call another time theimage again

Comment: you have no control over headers of a 3rd party unless you place a cache in front, i.e reverse proxy / cdn

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It is exactly what I would like to do, how could I put one of these in place ?

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/reverseproxycachingexample/

Comment: I'm finally not so sure that it is what I need. I'm searching for a way to force a third storage party to put a cache control on the response header

Comment: What about my answer? Doesn't it work out of the box for you? I also know that Cloudinary can be a proxy between a 3rd party website and your app. Not sure that you need to struggle so much for this to work, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When your website is hosted, your browser should cache the image by itself without you to really do anything.
Locally, it won't work but if you host it, your browser will see that the same image is called twice and it will just grab it from the cache (HTTP protocol is handling this AFAIK).

In my example, I called `sav2.png` when I first arrived on the page, it downloaded 4.6kB. Then, I soft reloaded the page and it used the cache (no additional call to the backend).

Those images are nothing special, bare simple `<img>` with the asset taken from `~/assets/images/sav2.png`.

[image]

---

Here is a WIP website for a friend: https://cyrielle-design.netlify.app/
This one uses Cloudinary but it does have the same pattern of fetching the image only once and then using cache for subsequent refreshs.