# NUXT.JS Storing/Cache API request

Tags: vue.js, caching, nuxt.js

I'm currently developing a NUXT.JS application, which gets JSON data from an API (Storyblok).

I could do with a little input / best practice advice on how to store/cache the API response - so that the API isn't requested multiple times when skipping through the pages.

I've looked at a million and one articles and tutorials and they all come back to Redis. Which is probably a little over the top for what I need.

I've added what I've done so far below - minus storing/caching.

Any and all input would be appreciated.

```html
<script>
export default {
  asyncData (context) {
    const version = context.query._storyblok || context.isDev ? 'draft' : 'published'
    const fullSlug = (context.route.path === '/' || context.route.path === '') ? 'home' : context.route.path
    return context.app.$storyapi.get(`cdn/stories/${fullSlug}`, {
      version
    }).then((res) => {
      return res.data
    }).catch((res) => {
      if (!res.response) {
        context.error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Failed to receive content form api' })
      } else {
        context.error({ statusCode: res.response.status, message: res.response.data })
      }
    })
  },

  data () {
    return {
      story: { content: {} }
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    this.$storybridge(() => {
      const { StoryblokBridge } = window
      const storyblokInstance = new StoryblokBridge()

      storyblokInstance.on('input', (event) => {
        if (event.story.id === this.story.id) {
          this.story.content = event.story.content
        }
      })

      storyblokInstance.on(['published', 'change'], (event) => {
        this.$nuxt.$router.go({
          path: this.$nuxt.$router.currentRoute,
          force: true
        })
      })
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use [memoization](https://www.maxpou.fr/vuejs-performance-improvement-with-memoization) if you do handle some big queries that may require a decent amount of time to compute. You can combine it with some Vuex comparison, to see if you need to refetch the data or not.

Browser's cache can do a good amount of work too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68087754/8816585. I guess that it depends of the files and if you can have proper headers.

Nuxt's [keep alive component](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/nuxt-components#keep-alive) based on [Vue's one](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) can also be somewhat useful, if you just want to toggle some components without refetching them every time.

[SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/) is an awesome implementation too! Here is the [Vue counterpart](https://github.com/Kong/swrv). Meanwhile, it was pretty tricky to setup initially last time I tried too.

There are probably even more solutions for the frontend, but I only know those. And also, the right answer depends of your needs too.